# POST a GD image resource using cURL

Tags: php, gd, php-curl

I'm trying to see if it's possible to use the GD library to create an image and attach it to a cURL POST request as if it were a PNG file in a multipart/form-data request.  I know I could just save the PNG file locally first and then attach it, but I'd like to see if it's possible to just take the image resource variable and pretend it's a valid file and have cURL send that, so that the receiving server thinks it got a normal file upload.

I don't know enough about creating complex requests in cURL, so maybe this is completely obvious, but I just want to create a POST request that appears to be from a HTML form that had a file attachment, without having to generate temporary files or store data elsewhere before sending the request.  Will cURL recognize a GD image resource as a valid PNG image file and allow it to be attached to the request, or does further work need to be done with it?

Comment: No, that is not directly possible. The file upload functionality the PHP cURL implementation provides is based on specifying the name of an actual file that cURL can read the data from.

Comment: But you can probably easily use a helper function such as https://gist.github.com/iansltx/a6ed41d19852adf2e496